# EAI_AGAIN when installing express from npm in Windows 7

Tags: node.js, express

I am using Windows 7 for development. I installed node.js 0.12.4 and npm is 2.10.1.

now i execute

```
npm intall express --save
```

but face the following error message:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "c:\\Program Files\\nnode_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "express" "--save"
npm ERR! node v0.12.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.10.1
npm ERR! code EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo

npm ERR! getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     d:\meandev\chat\npm-debug.log
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: What does the `npm-debug.log` file contain?

Answer (score 6):

I found solution here.

Its a network issue. in my previous network there is a proxy setting. i have tried to install it without proxy it worked fine.

reference https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7348

Answer (score 2):

Updating npm worked for me.

For OSX, Linux - `npm install -g npm@latest` 
For Windows - 
Step-1 :  Navigate to `%ProgramFiles%\nodejs\node_modules\npm` and copy the npmrcfile to another folder or the desktop. Then open cmd.exe and run the following commands:  
`cd %ProgramFiles%\nodejs`
`npm install npm@latest`
Step-2 : Copy the npmrc file back into `%ProgramFiles%\nodejs\node_modules\npm`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case rebooting server and trying again worked.