# npm install angular error ubuntu

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ubuntu

Helloo, am starting to learn angular and while trying to install angular by **npm install angular** on ubuntu 16.04LTS am getting the following error:

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-64-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "angular"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:443
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/hillux/npm-debug.log
```

some help will be appreciated guys.

Comment: its a network problem https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7348

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30702702/eai-again-when-installing-express-from-npm-in-windows-7

Comment: Can it be on my end ? Am connected to fast internet

Comment: it should be.. otherwise there would be more than one person with this issue.:) perhaps you are behind a proxy?

Comment: Okay, guess that's the problem. Lemme check how to go about it. Thanks Suraj

Answer (score -1):

```
Enter command in terminal
```

npm cache clean

chmod -R 777 directory where u installing npm 
eg:(chmod -R 777 /root/mydesktop)

npm install

Comment: after following this am now getting the following:                                                                                             /home/hillux
└── angular@1.6.2 

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/hillux/package.json'
npm WARN hillux No description
npm WARN hillux No repository field.
npm WARN hillux No README data
npm WARN hillux No license field.

Comment: Hello Hillux ,i think angular is installed in your home directory check there if u want to see install to another directory and delete from home directory because it install globally

Comment: Cool. I finally located it. So it means if it's installed globally I can use it in anywhere as long as am in the home directory?